# How do I pass over an error in pymol/python?

Tags: python, pymol

I'm trying to find the distances between residues of a protein in pymol using a python script, which calls the pymol command cmd.get_distance. However, sometimes there are multiple atom assignments, which causes an error:

```
GetDistance-Error: Selection 2 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
```

I want to skip over sites that have this problem so I'm trying to use try/pass:

```
try:
    cmd.get_distance(atom2)
except GetDistance-Error:
    pass
```

However, it tells me that there is no such error message:

```
NameError: global name 'GetDistance' is not defined.
```

How do I tell it to pass this error? isn't GetDistance-Error the error?

Comment: You will most probably need to capture something like `pymol.some_class.GetDistance-Error`. For the exact details, just do a `import pymol` in your `ipython` shell, and then use `dir(pymol)` to get list of associated objects.

Comment: The other way is to capture the generic exception, i.e. do a `except Exception: pass` which is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think this can be an exception, because of the hyphen: `GetDistance-Error` is not a valid identifier for an exception. Do the docs help?

Comment: Try handling `except pymol.CmdException: ` instead of `except GetDistance-Error:`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue. I want to catch the error from pymols cmd.get_distance. In my case, one (or both) of the selections does not contain an atom at all (instead of 2).

This answer will not clarify handling error in pymol scripting but resolve the issue itself.

So instead of catching the error, you could check before if there is exactly 1 atom in your selection.

Erroneous code:

```
PyMOL>dist = cmd.get_distance("///A/44/CA","///A/60/CA")
GetDistance-Error: Selection 1 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
```

Optimized code:

```
PyMOL>p1 = cmd.select("p1","///A/44/CA")
PyMOL>p2 = cmd.select("p2","///A/60/CA")
PyMOL>dist = "N/A"
PyMOL>if p1 == 1 and p2 == 1: dist = cmd.get_distance("p1","p2")
```

So instead of catching the error, you check the requirements (one atom per selection) for the get_distance command. If you run a continuous code, the dist = "N/A" is needed, otherwise you will falsely get the last assignment of the distance.

Answer (score 0):

my attempt :

```
import pymol

from pymol import cmd, CmdException


print(' pymol version : ', pymol.cmd.get_version())


# pymol.finish_launching()


# cmd.feedback( "disable" , "all" , "errors")  # funziona !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  removes print di errors



cmd.load('2p09.pdb' , '2p09')

cmd.select('all_waters', 'resn HOH')

cmd.remove('all_waters')


cmd.select('atom1', 'resi 16  and name CA')


try:
    a = cmd.get_distance('atom1')



except Exception as e:
    
    print('e ---------------> ',e ,' type ---> ', type(e))
    print('e.message ---> ',e.message)
    
    
try:
    a = cmd.get_distance('atom1')


except CmdException as e:
    
    
    print('e ---------------> ',e ,' type ---> ', type(e))
    
    print('e.message ---> ',e.message)
    
    print('e.label ---> ',e.label)
    
    print('e.traceback ---> ',e.__traceback__)
    
    
    print('e.with_traceback  ---> ',e.with_traceback(e.__traceback__) )
```

output:

```
 pymol version :  ('2.3.0', 2.001, 2001000, 1582201323, '', 0)
 PyMOL not running, entering library mode (experimental)
Selector-Error: Invalid selection name "pk2".
pk2<--
GetDistance-Error: Selection 2 invalid.
e --------------->   Error:   type --->  <class 'pymol.CmdException'>
e.message --->  
Selector-Error: Invalid selection name "pk2".
pk2<--
GetDistance-Error: Selection 2 invalid.
e --------------->   Error:   type --->  <class 'pymol.CmdException'>
e.message --->  
e.label --->  Error
e.traceback --->  <traceback object at 0x7efd34e6d680>
e.with_traceback  --->   Error:
```

Note that :

```
Selector-Error: Invalid selection name "pk2".
pk2<--
GetDistance-Error: Selection 2 invalid.
```

printing depends on `cmd.feedback( "disable" , "all" , "errors")` being coomented/uncommented out.

trying redirect both stdout and stderr with `from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr` won't result in same effect of `cmd.feedback( "disable" , "all" , "errors")` being uncommented out;
possibly because of:

> Note that the global side effect on sys.stdout means that this context manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses. However, it is still a useful approach for many utility scripts.

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

I believe somehow `CmdException` are not loaded at least for `get_distance` command